# storage performance test

Tags: linux, performance, storage

So we have some operational Red-hat Linux on physical servers and company are we decided to migrate them to VM's. I wonder if they have same performance on writing and reading from disks. they are database servers and this is important to know performance wouldn't decrease. I wonder if someone have this experience and suggest a best practice for it.

Note: It's important to test with cache enable and disabled.

Comment: it largely depends on what kind of virtualization solution you are going to use. you may easily find the performance stats for that as well

Comment: It's a big company and we are not informed of the virtualization solution and we just should test the performance black box. for example test write and read rate on both and compare together.

Comment: ok , then run an IO intensive job on physical and then run the same job on virtual and compare

Comment: You can use `blktrace` and `blkparse` to analyze your current workload and attempt to simulate that kind of workload on the virtual system as best you can and make note of whether or not it takes too long. There's almost always a performance drop when you go virtual, the question is whether the loss in performance really matters when compared to the administrative ease and ROI for resource allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to test the I/O of your solutions by using the command `dd`.
Try reading from `/dev/zero` and writing to a file residing on the disk you wish to test. **Writing** example below.

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/testfile bs=2G count=1
```

Results for my virtual (VMWare) CentOS for reference:

```
0+1 records in;
0+1 records out;
2147479552 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 32.6726 s, 65.7 MB/s
```

For testing the **read** capabilities try running the following. Keep in mind for best results make sure to **run this test at random times** to establish baseline. Additionally for more tests look at
`hdparm -t -T /dev/*`

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# dd if=/home/testfile of=/dev/null
```

Comment: `dd` isn't usually a good load testing tool unless your workload consists mainly of copying large files around. Databases are going to have a lot of random reads and a varying level of writes. They also need to know more about performance than just speed of the underlying operations, they need to know how they affect the application's performance. For instance if the application does a lot of writes that are async to the application, then long write times don't matter as much as long reads.

Comment: how can I test with cashed enabled or disabled?

Comment: @Bratchley added more to OP to address reading. Keep in mind this very same process can be applied to multiple files or taking an approach to measure latency of drives using dd by small block sizes and more counts.
Amirjj I am not entirely sure but I believe in fstab you can add option sync to address turning it off.

Comment: @Nxadmin1 any test that uses `dd` will likely be unusable unless you just have some problem with reads/writes in general. You can add enough variation if you get kind of elaborate with your script but at that point you're pretty much just re-creating load testing tools that already exist.  Also "random reads" doesn't necessarily mean reads that happen at random time periods, it's usually more about testing how I/O seems to behave if you give it a bunch of reads of varying sizes, throw a few writes in there, a few reads after that, etc. It's more about sequence than time.

Comment: Ultimately, load should really be generated at the application level since it's usually really difficult to simulate load effectively otherwise. You just do the tracing/analysis on the I/O if you think that's where you're getting caught up at. Different workloads can exhibit different behaviors. For example, if your writes are only slow after a lot of reads that may be important if that usually means your application is about to do something that requires a synchronous write and will thus wait. That may affect how you choose to tune the system and what trade-offs you're interested in making.

Comment: Also, to the OP, disabling caching pre-4.0 is a bit lame. You have to just continually `drop_caches` prior to starting your test but even then the cache builds up during the load test. In 4.0 they introduced the `dax` mount option which always bypasses the page cache.